# iPhone file transfer

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement iTunes built-in App “File Sharing” feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241107/how-to-implement-itunes-built-in-app-file-sharing-feature)

How do I enable my iPhone application to receive files through the apps tab in iTunes? If you can point me at the proper documentation, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be the documentation you’re looking for:

- [Technical Note TN2152: Document Transfer Strategies](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2009/tn2152.html)