# how to upload files to iphone app

Tags: ios

For some app like MyPDFs, when connect to mac ,
you can upload files into the app via itunes.

in itunes, There is "File Sharing", and I also want to share files with my App.

I'd like to know how to do it~

thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be found answered in the following questions:

[How to implement iTunes built-in App "File Sharing" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241107/how-to-implement-itunes-built-in-app-file-sharing-feature)

[Allow iPhone application to sync with iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654291/allow-iphone-application-to-sync-with-itunes)

[iTunes Documents Directory in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818213/itunes-documents-directory-in-my-app)